# I am trying to use a function in my project. But the console shows error

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to add an event listener, but I am facing a problem in the console. Can anyone take a look at my code?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead `document.querySelectorAll` which return a collection you have to use `document.querySelector()`. Then it would work.

But if you have multiple delete Buttons then use: `document.querySelectorAll`. Afterwards you must iterate this collection to add an EventListener to every element.

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');
btns.forEach(b => b.addEventListener('click', () => {
   // and action
}))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried, but unfortunately, that doesn't work.

Comment: can you share you html please. paste it to your question please